# Unable to understand on getting the value

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automated-tests

I'm writing a selenium code to do the below thing.

1. Enter value in text box.
2. Select the dropdown value.
3. Select a radio button.
4. Hit the go button.

When I do this, I will get a list of results and I want to get the heading of the first result block.

Below is my code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\home\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www2.chubb.com/us-en/find-agent-page.aspx");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tbAddress']")).sendKeys("60089");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cphHeroContent_drpDistanceMiles']")).sendKeys("2");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cphHeroContent_rdType_0']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cphHeroContent_btnSearch']")).click();

        String title = driver.getTitle().toString();
        System.out.println(title);

        Thread.sleep(10000L);

        String getHeadingTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='chubbAgentData']/li/h2")).toString();
        System.out.println(getHeadingTitle);

    }
}
```

In my code, I'm able to get step1, 2, 3 done and I able to get the title name in my console.

It is giving me the below exception when trying to get the heading text.

> JavaScript error: https://www2.chubb.com/us-en/find-agent-page.aspx,
> line 2: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
>
> JavaScript warning:
> https://www2.chubb.com/_Global-Assets/js/jquery-webdriver.js, line 1:
> Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //#
> instead [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP
> (320d5e47-8575-4566-9622-d8275cf72ded)] -> xpath:
> .//*[@id='chubbAgentData']/li/h2]

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `toString()` method - use `getText()`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='chubbAgentData']/li/h2")).getText();
```