# How do I wait for a page refresh in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

This is an extension to my previous question [Unable to understand on getting the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256484/unable-to-understand-on-getting-the-value)

Here the case is like below.

Based on the zipcode the result vary.

Currently I've the below content in a file.

```
99546
60089
```

and my code is as below.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\home\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www2.chubb.com/us-en/find-agent-page.aspx");

        try {
            File file = new File("zip.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tbAddress']")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cphHeroContent_drpDistanceMiles']")).sendKeys("Select Distance");

                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tbAddress']")).sendKeys(line);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cphHeroContent_drpDistanceMiles']")).sendKeys("2");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cphHeroContent_rdType_0']")).click();

                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cphHeroContent_btnSearch']")).click();

                String title = driver.getTitle().toString();
                System.out.println(title);



                WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(
                        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/div/div[1]/div[@style='']")));

                String getHeadingTitle = element.getText();

                System.out.println(line + "\t" + getHeadingTitle);

            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
99546   No Results Found
Find Agent Page
60089   1 Agents Found. Please scroll down to see a list of agents.
```

current result:

```
99546   No Results Found
Find Agent Page
60089   No Results Found
```

Issue:
I'm using the below code.

```
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(
                            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/div/div[1]/div[@style='']")));
```

Initially, this block is hidden so i'm waiting till it is visible, from second time, the same block gets updated instead of going invisible and coming back visible.
This is the value that is retrieved from the previous submit, on the first submit.
Please let me know how can I get the updated values.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can use `Thread.sleep(4000)` method for make pause for few seconds (Its not a proper solution) So you will be able to get the text by  making  pause in your script .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe, you can solved it by asserting that an element which was originally present on the page, is not present on the page right after refresh

- refreshAndWait or clickAndWait on refresh button
- assertElementNotPresent page_specific_element -> check that refresh
  was really executed
- pause 3000ms -> wait for refresh to end
- assertElementPresent page_specific_element -> check that refresh was

  really executed and same page has been loaded

Answer (score 9):

The best answer to this question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32278904/349169

```
WebElement elementOldPage = driver.findElement(By.id("yourid"));

... do login etc ...

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(elementOldPage));

WebElement elementNewPage = driver.findElement(By.id("yourid"));
```